# in_array no match and the text is in Array

Tags: php

My File : (**ip_tor.csv**)

```
a
1.34.163.57
1.64.131.242
1.123.153.166
1.209.122.55
```

My Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => 1.34.163.57
    [2] => 1.64.131.242
    [3] => 1.123.153.166
    [4] => 1.209.122.55
)
```

**My in_array_r function :**

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $item)
    {
        if(($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict)))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My Code :

```
$tor = file('ips_tor.csv');

if(in_array_r('1.34.163.57', $tor))
   echo '<span style="color: red;display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;">OK</span>';

else
   echo '<span style="color: black; display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;">Not Ok</span>';
```

"a" is in Array, on [0], but when i test, my script say : Not Ok but a is in array :/

Any idea ?

Comment: Post your in_array_r function. Can probably just use in_array

Comment: `file('ips_tor.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`

Comment: @rjdown : i have add in_array_r function !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `in_array` instead of `in_array_r`.

Maybe it will help if you trim all the elements in the `$tor` array:

```
$tor = file('ips_tor.csv');
$tor = array_map('trim', $tor);

// In case of only newlines, you can add the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag to file() and skip the array_map:
// $tor = file('ips_tor.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if(in_array('1.34.163.57', $tor))
    echo '<span style="color: red;display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;">OK</span>';

else
    echo '<span style="color: black; display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;">Not Ok</span>';
```

Will result in:

> OK

Comment: Or if only newlines just use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` with `file()`.

Comment: That is true, I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the array returned from `$tor = file('ip_tor.csv');` probably have newlines or some other whitespace. Try `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and you may be able to see them. A quick fix is to remove all that using trim.

```
$tor = array_map('trim', $tor);
```

Comment: Or if only newlines just use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` with `file()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using `in_array_r`?
We do not know what this function is.

In fact the following code outputs "YES":

```
$arr = array(
    "a",
    "1.34.163.57",
    "1.64.131.242",
    "1.123.153.166",
    "1.209.122.55"
);

echo (in_array('1.34.163.57', $arr)) ? "YES" : "NO";
```